# Add column with default null value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use rails with postgreSQL, I  want to add a new column with a default null value, 
do I have to specify the default null value?

```
add_column :posts, :string, default: null
```

Comment: `posts` is table name, `string` is datatype, then where did you miss column name ? Also you do not need to set default to null for string as its default value is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify it. When you add new column to table without default value all the values will be null.
Also: note that in ruby the equivalent of psql `Null` value is `nil`.